# Update FieldStorageConfig for a field in an update hook properly?

Tags: 8, entities

I need to update the allowed values option on an list_integer field. For reasons at the moment, I can't just update and export the configuration and import it on production until we implement config_ignore. I also do not want to edit several block types to update a few field(s) coming up across several environments - so if I can script it and save time that is what I want to do.

In an update hook, I am trying this:

```
/**
 * Update the result options for the Result Count field.
 */
function mymodule_update_8001(&$sandbox) {
  $allowed_values = [];

  for ($x = 1; $x < 16; $x++) {
    $allowed_values[$x] = (string) $x;
  }

  $allowed_values[50] = '50';
  $allowed_values[75] = '75';
  $allowed_values[100] = '100';

  $old_config = FieldStorageConfig::load('block_content.field_result_count');
  $new_config = $old_config->createDuplicate();
  $new_config->original = $new_config;
  $new_config->enforceIsNew(FALSE);
  $new_config
    ->setSetting('allowed_values', $allowed_values)
    ->save();
}
```

It appeared to add the new values to the field, but the terminal spit this out when running the database update:

```
>  [warning] assert(): Cannot load the "field_storage_config" entity with NULL ID. failed EntityStorageBase.php:249
>  [warning] array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! EntityStorageBase.php:266
```

Is this the proper way to update an existing field?

Comment: Can't you just load, modify and save the config entity? Do you need the three extra lines for creating a duplicate?

Comment: So no duplicate needed? Was going off an example I saw online.

Comment: No, cloning and setting the original is done by core automatically if needed. The example is probably from core entity base classes.

Comment: This example (https://www.hook42.com/blog/ride-danger-zone-how-update-drupal-8-field-settings-without-losing-any-data) *doesn't* work because of these lines `$new_config = $old_config->createDuplicate();
  $new_config->original = $new_config;
  $new_config->enforceIsNew(FALSE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was almost there initially, but thanks to 4k4 this is one way to amend an allowed value list with new values:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 *
 * The first action updates the result options for the Result Count field.
 * Options should be 1-15, 50, 75 and 100.
 */
function mymodule_update_8001(&$sandbox) {
  $allowed_values = [];

  for ($x = 1; $x < 16; $x++) {
    $allowed_values[$x] = (string) $x;
  }

  $allowed_values[50] = '50';
  $allowed_values[75] = '75';
  $allowed_values[100] = '100';

  $config = FieldStorageConfig::load('ENTITY_TYPE.FIELD_ID');
  $config
    ->setSetting('allowed_values', $allowed_values)
    ->save();
}
```